# Running Chrome in app mode with multiple tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

So I have set up an app shortcut for YouTube in Chrome. When I click this, I get a new window that opens to YouTube's website. Works great. However, if I want to for example open videos in a new tab, these will be redirected to my main Chrome window, which is not what I want as I would rather have them as tabs in the YouTube app window.

Is this possible with some flag?